# Displaying specific data from the database in a dependent select box in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

How can I load data from my database into a select box? This select box is dependent to another select box.

I will need to update the details of my products. When I click the specific product in the table, the product details will load on my update view. Everything is almost fine except for one select box namely `size` select box, which the data didn't show.

I tried many solutions but none of them works.

This is my product table view:

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="main">

    <div class="table-wrapper">
       <div id="content">
<legend class="text-danger"><h1>Product List</h1></legend>
            <?php   $tableAttr = array(
                    'table_open' => '<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover" id="item_tbl">',
                    );
                $item_table = $this->table->set_heading('No.','PRODUCT CODE','PRODUCT DESCRIPTION','BRAND', 'CATEGORY', 'SIZE','ORIGINAL PRICE','ACTION');
                $item_table = $this->table->set_template($tableAttr);
                $num = 0;
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $itemName = urlencode($item->prod_desc);
                    $num++;
                    $item_table = $this->table->add_row($num, $item->prod_code, $item->prod_desc, $item->brand_name,$item->category_name,$item->size,'₱'. $item->original_price,"

                        <a href='".base_url("item/update/$itemName")."'><button class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>EDIT</button></a> 
                        ");
                }
                echo $this->table->generate($item_table);  ?>
                </div>

</div>                            
</div>
```

So when I click edit button it will another form the `product_update_view.php`:

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="main" style="padding: 20px;">
    <?php echo form_open("item/item_update/$item->prod_id");
     echo form_fieldset('<h3 class="text-info">Update Item</h3>');  ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_code" value="<?php echo $item->prod_code ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cur_name" value="<?php echo $item->prod_desc ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cur_category" value="<?php echo $item->category_name ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cur_brand" value="<?php echo $item->brand_name ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cur_size" value="<?php echo $item->size ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cur_price" value="<?php echo $item->original_price ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for='prod_code'>Product Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="up_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->prod_code; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for='prod_name'>Product Description:</label>
    <input type="text" name=up_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->prod_desc; ?>">
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for='prod_name'>Brand:</label>
<select name="brand" class="form-control">
<option value="Select Brand" selected="selected">Select Brand</option>


    <?php foreach($brand as $br):?>
<option value="<?php echo $br->brand_id; ?>" <?php if ($br->brand_id == $item->brand_id) {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>><?php echo $br->brand_name?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    </div>      

      <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                        <option value="Select Brand"> Select Category</option>
                        <?php foreach($category as $cat): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $cat->category_id; ?>" <?php if ($cat->category_id == $item->category_id) {echo "selected='selected'";} ?>><?php echo $cat->category_name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sizes">Size:</label>
                     <select class="form-control" name="category" id="sizes">
                        <option value="Select size"> Select Size</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label for='prod_price'>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->original_price; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_account" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" >
    </div>
</div>


<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/jquery.js"></script>


    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#category').on('change', function(){
                var category_id = $(this).val();
                if(category_id === '')

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/get_sizes",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {'category_id' : category_id},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                           $('#sizes').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error occur...!!');
                        }
                    });
                }
           });

        });
    </script>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The controller (`item.php`):

```
public function update($name) {
                 $this->load->model('Dependent_model', 'dep_model', TRUE);
    $this->load->model('brand_model');
            $data['category'] = $this->dep_model->get_category_query();
    $data['brand'] = $this->brand_model->getBrandName();
    $this->load->model('item_model');
    $data['item'] = $this->item_model->item_info($name);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('side_menu');
    $this->load->view('product_update_view.php',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

The controller of dependent select box (`welcome.php`):

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Dependent_model', 'dep_model', TRUE);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['category'] = $this->dep_model->get_category_query();
        $this->load->view('new_product', $data);
    }
    public function get_sizes()
    {
        $category_id = $this->input->post('category_id');
        $sizes = $this->dep_model->get_sizes_query($category_id);
        if(count($sizes)>0)
        {
            $pro_select_box = '';
            $pro_select_box .= '<option value="Select Size">Select Size</option>';
            foreach ($sizes as $sz) {
                $pro_select_box .='<option value="'.$sz->size_id.'">'.$sz->size.'</option>';
            }
            echo json_encode($pro_select_box);
        }
    }
}
```

Models (`item_model.php`):

```
public function item_info ($itemName) {
        $this->load->database();

        $this->db->select('products.*,category.category_name,sizes.size,brand.brand_name')
                        ->from('products')
                        ->from('category');
                      $this->db->from('sizes');
                        $this->db->from('brand');
                        $this->db->where('products.category_id = category.category_id');
                   $this->db->where('products.size_id = sizes.size_id');
                   $this->db->where('products.brand_id = brand.brand_id');
                  $this->db->where('prod_desc', urldecode($itemName));  
                $result=$this->db->get();


        return $result->row();
}
```

The dependent select box model (`dependent_model`):

```
<?php
class Dependent_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_category_query()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('category');
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function get_sizes_query($category_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('sizes', array('category_id' => $category_id));
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

The problem is it does not show the size of the specific product in `product_update` view.

Comment: I think problem on your JavaScript condition first of all why you use if(category_id === "") that men's when you change your category and get the id but for your condition it will be not enter in this condition so, you need to change condition if (category_id != "").  Another thing is if you want to load size first time onload page then you pass default selected category id

Comment: can you show me a example code?

Comment: He's entirely right, you are never entering the condition because you only do Ajax if it doesn't have a value and you want it to do Ajax if it does have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this jquery.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/jquery.js"></script>


    <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>dropdown/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var cat_id = $("#category option:selected").val();
        if(cat_id != '')
                 $.fn.ajaxCall(cat_id);
         ajaxCall(category_id);
           $('#category').on('change', function(){
                var category_id = $(this).val();
                if(category_id != '')
                 $.fn.ajaxCall(category_id);
                });

             $.fn.ajaxCall = function(category_id){
                   $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/get_sizes",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {'category_id' : category_id},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                           $('#sizes').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error occur...!!');
                        }
                    });
            }       
           });


    </script>
```